# Can't disable SSL connection in MVC6 app after adding RequireHttpsAttribute to Filters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, https, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an issue of redirecting me to https every time I run project.
In result I get ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.

All I want is to have standard Http connection while debugging.

Issue came after adding following code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(config =>
    {
       config.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
    });
}
```

After removing this filter still have this problem: site tries to connect through SSL.

Also tried to run this app in another browser, which lead to interesting behavior: first time I run app in another browser I have Http connection and page runs ok, but when I redirect to next action new page loads in Https, so it throws this SSL error. After running app in same browser again I get Https connection even at first page.

Please help :)

Comment: any `[RequireHttps]` lying around?

Comment: Nope, there is no RequireHttps attribute enabled.

Answer (score 0):

After recreating the project and moving code from previous project, problem was resolved. Still don't know why this problem occurred. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. Try clearing your browser cache and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Its because RequireHttps issues a 301 (permanent redirect). Since you applied that to all your requests you can not use http again as most major browsers cache this indefinitely.
If your lucky and you only used this in testing clearing your browser cache will resolve it.
If you published this site your out of luck.

Its basically a one way street I'm campaigning for 302 to be the default to stop this weirdness and save a few devs hours of head scratching.